# How to print first 3 strings from 1 input variable

Tags: python

[My desired output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdG4L.png)
So I'm trying to make a code that makes a social media account.
But the twist is when you give your details, the output will say, "This is how your profile will be shown to others." It prints your name, job, and state you live in. This is all asked with input.
I having trouble with the part you only print the 3.

Here is my code:

```py
print ('   Welcome to SnapChat  ')

print (' ')

print (' ')

profile = input("Enter your profile details in this format (first_name,job_title,current_state_you_live_in,email_id,phone_number): ")

prof = profile.split(",")

print (' ')

print ('Your Profile Details Are As Follows')

for x in prof:
    print (x,'\n')
```

Comment: use array index `prof[1]` or slice `prof[1:4]`

Comment: The first thing you should do is check the length of your *prof* list. If it's not 5 then you're in trouble. Input validation is always critical

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the `.split(',')` which gives you a list!

To print the first three elements, you could simply do

```
for x in prof[:3]:
    print(x, end='\n\n') # Adds two nextline characters
```

## List Slicing

Considering the question is really basic, I'd like to explain further on what list slicing is. Essentially, given a list you can access it using indices (i.e. first object is , second object).

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
print(my_list[0])
print(my_list[1])
print(my_list[2])
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

You can also do list slicing,

```
print(my_list[:2]) #prints all elements UP TO element 2 (non-inclusive)
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

You can think of more creative ways on how you wish to slice, for example starting from an index to another

```
print(my_list[1:2]) #print element at index 1, and UP TO index 2 (not-inclusive)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: I tried that but It prints them on the same line with [ ] and " "

Comment: The code would not print them on the same line, as `print()` statement automatically adds an invisible nextline (`\n`) character. What is the exact output format you're looking for?

Comment: Oh ok, the output desired is in the link in the question

Comment: And what do you mean by user_attr?

Comment: I've edited to work for your requirements. However, this is frankly really basic questions you should try searching online further before asking a question in future.

Comment: I am a beginner in Python and believe me, I searched online a lot.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you more context on list slicing. Cheers.